# Error after installing healthcloud in a scratch org: "Invalid field PermissionsCreateReportFolders for PermissionSet"

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, health-cloud

After installing the Health Cloud managed package in a scratch org, we're receiving a post install exception email with the error:

"Invalid field PermissionsCreateReportFolders for PermissionSet", originating from:

Class.HealthCloudGA.HcPermissionSettingsPostInstallJobs.CreatePermSetSystemPermissions.addSystemPerms: line 127

I don't see anything obvious in [the scratch org definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) about "report" or "folder."

Why are we getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the answer on this Github comment: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/332#issuecomment-600246931

Add this to your scratch org definition file:

```
"analyticsSettings": {
    "enableAnalyticsSharingEnable": true
}
```

As with many things involving scratch orgs, this isn't documented anywhere, and trying to Google for scratch org folder permissions wasn't fruitful.